# ¿Cómo lograr el efecto de el login de Wix?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css3, material-design

Quiero imitar el efecto `placeholder` de los `inputs` en el login de [Wix](http://wix.com), cuando el foco se coloca en un `input`, su texto de `placeholder` se coloca arriba del `input` y en una letra más pequeña.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El efecto se puede lograr usando solo `CSS`, puntualmente las propiedades  [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform) y [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Transiciones_de_CSS)

```css
.animate-label {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.animate-label label {
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1);
  transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}
.animate-label input {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
}
.animate-label input:focus {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #cfc;
}
.animate-label input:focus + label {
  transform: translate3d(-5px,-20px,0) scale(.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="animate-label">
  <input />
  <label>Usuario</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @MarcosGallardo la pregunta es interesante para el diseño de formularios, en lo personal como se quita aquel efecto borroso en el texto al realizar el foco -> `input`,

Comment: @J.Doe, en lugar de hacer un `scale`, se podría modificar el `font-size`.

Answer (score 4):

Ese es un efecto de la especificación Material Design de Google, hay varias librerías que proveen una implementación de esta especificación, sin embargo esas librerías proveen toda una biblioteca con componentes de esta especificación, aquí encontré en internet un ejemplo que usa CSS para llevar a cabo únicamente el efecto que deseas.

https://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/gbddEj

```css
h1,
input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
button {
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

h1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #18aa8d;
  color: white;
  line-height: 150%;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

form {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 260px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

form h1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  margin: 40px 25px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #1abc9c;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #1abc9c 4%);
  background-position: -200px 0;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #0e6252;
}

input:focus,
input:valid {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder,
input:valid::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #1abc9c;
  font-size: 11px;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  visibility: visible !important;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: #1abc9c;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.follow {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #03a9f4;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px calc(50% - 21px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.follow i {
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: margin-right 0.2s ease;
}

.follow:hover {
  width: 134px;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
}

.follow:hover i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>Material Design Text Input With No Extra Markup</h1>
  <input placeholder="Username" type="text" required="">
  <input placeholder="Password" type="password" required="">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<a class="follow" href="https://twitter.com/mildrenben" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Follow Me</a>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Te aconsejo que en vez de solo poner el enlace externo incluyas el `snippet` en tu respuesta, te llevarías un +1 mío porque ese enlace tiene la respuesta que quiere el OP...

Comment: Entiendo, es solo que considere que no sería justo copiar un código que no es de mi autoría, si hay alguna regla que estoy infringiendo agradezco que me la hagan conocer, soy nuevo en la comunidad.

Comment: Puedes hacer lo que te digo, colocar el `snippet` en tu respuesta y hacer una cita de tipo "fuente: link